# Does Xamarin support "navigation" and "anim" folders for AndroidX?

Tags: android, xamarin

I know the Xamarin AndroidX navigation NuGet packages are in preview and able to be installed right now, but for the navigation package it is necessary to create a navigation graph under the navigation Resources folder. However when you add such a folder you'll get an error like this:

`/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Aapt.targets(3,3): Error APT1045: invalid resource directory name: /user/mobile/src/Android/obj/AndroidEmulator/Debug/res/navigation " navigation". (APT1045) (Android)`

Is there support out there for these folders or is it too early?

Comment: Have you tried enabling aapt2? I know anim is supported, never heard of a "navigation" folder in an Android project before though

Comment: So I spoke with someone from MS on the xamarinchat slack and it looks like they don't support the navigation folder yet. I've created a feature request for it. This is where the navigation concept comes from:

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently not supported by Xamarin.Android.